# Google Dataflow Key Distribution On Reshuffle After Autoscaling Event

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm experiencing some weird behaviour with keyed state in my dataflow job when it scales from 45 worker nodes to 100 nodes.

My code is keying input data, then using a *Reshuffle* function to redistribute the keys. The first ParDo function after the shuffle performs a sequence check on the data for each key and stores last sequence number in a state variable, so it can compare the next message against it. The data is ordered in kafka.

After an autoscaling event occurs it seems the previously processed state is no longer available for a given key. Is this expected behaviour in dataflow? When autoscaling occurs are key ranges in dataflow recalculated?, if so does that mean I need to store the processed sequence numbers in an external datastore so I can rebuild after each autoscaling event? I can't find any official documentation on Google docs about what happens to key distribution during autoscaling.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be seeing are retries.If the autoscaling event happens before the state has been persisted, then the events will be retried on the new machine. Dataflow guarantees exactly once within a pipeline, so if the input events are  retried on the new worker, the state on the new worker must also reflect the state before those events.

If you are using logging to determine that state was written, you'll observe these retries. However state is persistent, it just doesn't necessarily line up with your log statements due to these retries.